# Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такое передвижение свайпами?

Tags: android, android-fragment, material-design, swipelayout

Может какая-то библиотека есть? или это всё фрагменты?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вас интересует индикатор сверху?

Comment: да, при нажании (или при свайпах) переход на другие лейауты и передвижение кнопок (какой экран прикрепленная к нему кнопка по центу)

Comment: Не надо ссылок. Хотя бы просто картинку покажите, объясните словами что на ней и поправьте заголовок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для свайпов между фрагментами используйте ViewPager. К нему в адаптер пускаете нужные вам фрагменты радуйтесь! Ниже приведу код для для базового решения.

Создаем лейаут с viewpager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

После чего создаём несколько фрагментов, которые собственно и будут в нашем viewpager.
Следующим шагом будет создание адаптера и присвоение его нашему viewpager:

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        // Возвращает общее количество фрагментов
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        // Возвращает фрамгент, который будет отображаться сейчас
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
            case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                return SecondFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Возвращает заголовок (например, если используете TabLayout)
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }

    }
```

Ну а после и назначаем наш адаптер нашему viewpager в коде активити:

```
...
ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
...
```

Comment: Автор про индикатор спрашивал.

Comment: Тогда просто использовать tabLayout в придачу, как я написал. Это буквально пара строк ещё и всё.